# How to iterate items in Multi-dimensional Systemverilog uvm_queue

Tags: multidimensional-array, system-verilog, uvm

I’m trying to create an object which is constructed from array of uvm_queue. The idea is that each item in the array is for itself a uvm_queue ( i.e. a list of items). The Queue type is a class.

The problem is I can’t manage to iterate the items of a single ‘memory ID’ list.

When I compile I get the following Error:

if (ml_mem_array[mem_id][ii].m_addr == a_addr)

xmelab: *E,CUVNAA (./utils.sv,47|45): An index has been applied to an inappropriate type.

The code looks like this:

```
// ====================

class mem_entry extends uvm_object;
   
   int m_addr;

   int m_data;

endclass

// ====================

class memory extends uvm_object;

   uvm_queue#(mem_entry) ml_mem_array[2];

   function mem_entry get_mem_entry(int a_addr, int mem_id);

      int v_size;
      int ii;

      v_size = ml_mem_array[mem_id].size();

     if ((mem_id >= 2) || (v_size == 0))
        return null;

      for (ii=0 ; ii<=(v_size-1) ; ii=ii+1)
        begin
           if (ml_mem_array[mem_id][ii].m_addr == a_addr)
             return ml_mem_array[mem_id][ii];
        end
      return null;
   endfunction

endclass
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `get()` method of `uvm_queue` to access the internal queue elements

```
 for (int ii=0 ; ii<=(v_size-1) ; ii=ii+1)
    begin
       mem_entry entry = ml_mem_array[mem_id].get(ii);
       if (entry.m_addr == a_addr)
         return entry;
    end
```